# Sequelize - Limit model include contents grouping by column

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

## Current Sequelize Query

I am using this SequelizeJS query to grab product and price data.

```
models.products.findAll({
      where: Sequelize.where(Sequelize.fn('CONCAT_WS', ' ', Sequelize.col('brand'), Sequelize.col('name')),{ $like: `%${searchQuery}%`}),
      limit: limit,
      offset: offset,
      include: [{
        model: models.prices,
        group: ['sourceId']
      }],
      order: [
        ['name', 'desc'],
        [models.prices, 'createdAt', 'desc']
      ],
    });
```

The main issue lies within the `include` part of this query.

---

## Include query result example

My `prices` model columns looks like this, this is an example query of the contents of one of the includes.

```
id      price   createdAt  updatedAt               sourceId productId
4685    329.99  2018-03-06 17:47:13 2018-03-06 17:47:13 1   7
4466    399.00  2018-02-23 16:46:59 2018-02-23 16:46:59 1   7
3881    329.00  2017-11-16 13:13:15 2017-12-10 19:15:40 1   7
3749    339.99  2017-10-18 09:50:53 2017-10-18 09:50:53 3   7
2661    349.00  2017-08-08 13:57:07 2017-08-08 13:57:07 3   7
7       349.00  2017-08-03 17:01:24 2017-09-17 10:24:55 1   7
```

My goal is to group and limit by `sourceId`, however grouping by that column hasn't been my solution.

---

## Expected result

Instead of the above results, here is what I expect:

```
id       price  createdAt           updatedAt        sourceId productId
4685    329.99  2018-03-06 17:47:13 2018-03-06 17:47:13 1   7
3749    339.99  2017-10-18 09:50:53 2017-10-18 09:50:53 3   7
```

The difference here is it limits/groups per sourceId and only shows the most recently created row per sourceId.

Originally I was getting an error stating I am this mode for SQL: `sql_mode=only_full_group_by`, other users suggested removing this mode. It felt like a messy approach, but it did remove my error and fetch the results - however not as I expect.